# Где найти jar для support-v4

Tags: java, android

В Intellij Idea 2018.2 в android-проекте в коде объявлена переменная типа android.support.v4.util.ArraySet. Среда на этот класс не ругается, значит он есть в каком-то jar. Но в списке внешних библиотек в com.android.support:support-v4-26.1.0 (который aar) нет ни папки utils ни класса ArraySet, а только BuildConfig. Где найти aar или jar, в котором есть этот ArraySet.class ?

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Поставьте на его имя курсор, нажмите `ctrl+B`, потом мишень в шапке Project View

Comment: Да, все нашлось, спасибо! ))